# Setting a Substate enum based on a State enum

Tags: c#, enums

**Background:**

Let's take the example of an item being listed on an eCommerce website to explain this question. Perhaps you've got a bike for sale, and you attempt to list it upon a sales website,  choosing both a category and subcategory. Perhaps you might choose:

(Category > Subcategory)
Vehicles > Bikes

as the category and subcategory. Understandably, the Vehicles category has its own unique set of subcategories.

**Question:**

I have the following code for a class:

```
public class Listing 
{
    public Category ListingCategory { get; set; }
    public Subcategory ListingSubcategory { get; set; }

    public enum Category {
        Vehicles,
        Guitars,
        ExoticAnimals
    }
}
```

How can I allow subcategory selection to depend on the chosen category, such as in the background example? **I am happy not to use enums, if the solution works!**

Comment: What are you traing to do? Show you code

Comment: I don't think that Categories are usually a good candidate for being enums. If you add categories then you'll need to recompiles the code which is generally bad. Also I would imagine that you generally don't want to do compile time differentiation between categories that much. Usually I'd have a table of categories and subcategories in the database that would then have the dependencies built into its structure.

Comment: You can use a class for this, called Subcategory, which contains the Category as a property. (something like `class Subcategory { public Category Category { get; set; } }` , using Subcategory as the only property in your Listing class)

Comment: @Diamondo25: He wants the subcategory to be an enum too. And if you're going to change the subcat to a class I'd personally change the category too... :)

Comment: @Chris I'm happy not to use enums. I just wanna know a good solution for this; the categories will never be added to - I can guarantee that.

Comment: @NickBull: Well Ondrej's answer below gives the sort of structure that I had in mind. If you have a strict category/subcategory you might be able to make his solution simpler with distinct tables rather than self referencing ones but the concept is much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an abstract class which represents the subcategory. It'll get the category in its Ctor and will maintain a static map between a category and a list of subcategory items.

The SubcategoryItem can hold all the functionality (if any) you'd need from any single subcategory item.

```
public class SubcategoryItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Action WhatItDoes { get; set; }

    public SubcategoryItem(string name, Action trick)
    {
        Name = name;
        WhatItDoes = trick;
    }
}

public abstract class AbsSubcategory
{
    private static readonly IDictionary<Category, IList<SubcategoryItem>> mCategoriesMap = new Dictionary<Category, IList<SubcategoryItem>>();

    public abstract IList<SubcategoryItem> Subcategories { get; }

    protected AbsSubcategory(Category cat)
    {
        if (Subcategories != null) mCategoriesMap[cat] = Subcategories;
    }
}

public class VehiclesSubcategory : AbsSubcategory
{
    private static readonly IList<SubcategoryItem> mSubcategories;
    public override IList<SubcategoryItem> Subcategories
    {
        get { return mSubcategories; }
    }

    static VehiclesSubcategory()
    {
        mSubcategories = new List<SubcategoryItem>()
        {
            new SubcategoryItem("Bikes", () => { /* Do something */ } ),
            new SubcategoryItem("Cars", () => { /* Do something */ } ),
        };
    }

    public VehiclesSubcategory()
        : base(Category.Vehicles)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend following structure:

```
  public class Category {
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<Category> Children { get; set; }
  }
```

In database:

```
create table Categories (
   CategoryID int primary key not null identity(1,1),
   CategoryName nvarchar(50),
   ParentCategoryID int NULL
)

alter table Categories 
add constraint FK_Categories_ParentCategoryID
foreign key (ParentCategoryID)
references Categories(CategoryID)
```